# Domain Driven Design Exercise

Tags: domain-driven-design

I recently found out about Domain Driven Design and I liked it. However, it is quite overwhelming and requires quite of expertise to get it right. For this reason, I wanted to try to model a simple domain using DDD and event storming.
The domain is the following:

The application allows publishers to publish small articles or books. Both publishers and users can browse, read, "pin" articles and "follow" more than one publisher to get notification about their new articles. Lets say that publishers are the same as users, with the additional functionality that they can publish.
Users have free access. Publishers have only a subscription based access. Users have an hard limit on the number of articles they can pin. However, this limit can be increased by buying a subscription. Publishers have an hard limit on the number of articles they can publish. However, this limit can be increased by buying an advanced subscription.

This is what I modelled till now and it is only a small part of it:

[image]

The Article Bounded Context contains a single aggregate Portfolio. The Portfolio holds the owner  of the Portfolio, the created Articles entities and the ArticleQuotas ValueObject. To create an Article the Publisher has to go to the Portfolio, so that we can regulate the creation of new Articles. The Publisher can publish an Article of its Portfolio and the published Article will be visible in the PublishedArticle ReadModel. Finally, the PortfolioQuotas are regulated via events generated by the Subscription BoundedContext, by incrementing the PortfolioQuotas.
At first I was tempted to separate the concept of Article and Quotas, but then there is the problem of the eventual consistency between the creation of an Article and the Exceed of Quotas.

What I'm asking here is whether I'm going in the right direction and, otherwise, if you have some suggestions in modeling using Domain Driven Design.

Thank you very much